# Counting values in set types at the column

Tags: python, pandas

have a dataframe like below at the image

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bus':[{268},{23,200,268},{24},{24},{200,268}],
'problem':["Driver Issues" ,"Driver Issues" , "Timing Problem","Routing",
"Timing Problem"]})
```

bus column indicates the bus numbers and the problem column has the complains about buses. in the bus column, any row could have one or more bus numbers.

i'm trying to count every bus number, and its most common problem/issues/complains..  finding most common bus numbers and their most common complains.

but because of the set type, cant use Counter func.

output can be like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'busses':["268","24","200","23"],
'ComplainFrequency':["3" ,"2" , "2","1"]})
```

and

```
Bus no: 268
Coplains: 
Driver Issues:2
Timing Problem:1
 ....
```

Comment: Instead of pictures and link add your dataframe and desired output

Comment: right, i edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First flatten sets to new `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(c, b) for a, b in zip(df['bus'], df['problem']) for c in a], 
                    columns=['bus','problem'])
print (df1)
   bus         problem
0  268   Driver Issues
1  200   Driver Issues
2  268   Driver Issues
3   23   Driver Issues
4   24  Timing Problem
5   24         Routing
6  200  Timing Problem
7  268  Timing Problem
```

If there are sets of string values with `,`, so is necessary double flattening:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bus':[{'268'},{'23,200,268'},{'24'},{'24'},{'200,268'}], 
                   'problem':["Driver Issues" ,"Driver Issues" , "Timing Problem",
                              "Routing","Timing Problem"]})

print (df)
            bus         problem
0         {268}   Driver Issues
1  {23,200,268}   Driver Issues
2          {24}  Timing Problem
3          {24}         Routing
4     {200,268}  Timing Problem

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(d, b) for a, b in zip(df['bus'], df['problem']) 
                           for c in a 
                           for d in c.split(',')], 
                    columns=['bus','problem'])

print (df1)
   bus         problem
0  268   Driver Issues
1   23   Driver Issues
2  200   Driver Issues
3  268   Driver Issues
4   24  Timing Problem
5   24         Routing
6  200  Timing Problem
7  268  Timing Problem
```

And then use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df2 = df1.groupby('bus')['problem'].size().reset_index(name='ComplainFrequency')
print (df2)
   bus  ComplainFrequency
0  200                  2
1   23                  1
2   24                  2
3  268                  3

df3 = df1.groupby(['bus','problem']).size().reset_index(name='Coplains')
print (df3)
   bus         problem  Coplains
0  200   Driver Issues         1
1  200  Timing Problem         1
2   23   Driver Issues         1
3   24         Routing         1
4   24  Timing Problem         1
5  268   Driver Issues         2
6  268  Timing Problem         1
```

Comment: i edited the post for clarify the problem, can you look again, btw thx for your help

Comment: @nous - please check now.